# Foundation não funciona nada que usa Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

Estou carregando no cabeçalho o JQuery, foundation.min.js e foundation.css. Porém nada que necessita de JavaScript funciona, como *dropdown*, *slider*, etc. Não consigo encontrar solução em parte alguma. Como fazer o Foundation funcionar?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Foundation</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="foundation/css/foundation.min.css">
    <script src="foundation/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
<div class="medium-6 columns">

<a href="#" data-dropdown="drop1" class="button dropdown">Dropdown Button</a><br>
<ul id="drop1" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown">
<li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

O botão *dropdown* não funciona, embora tudo esteja sendo carregado normalmente. O código é idêntico ao da [documentação](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/).

Comment: Poderia disponibilizar algum exemplo?

Comment: mostre a parte do código que não está funcionando

Comment: Olá, @user7770, bemvindo ao [pt.so], por favor, confira os guias [about] e [ask]. Você pode [edit] sua pergunta para incluir mais detalhes.

Comment: Adicionei um exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que você se esqueceu de inicializar o foundation. Coloque isto logo antes do `</body>`, e o *dropdown* passará a funcionar:

```
<script>$(document).foundation();</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente, preferencialmente, colocar os javascript's ao final da página, antes do fechamento da tag Body. Abaixo disso você faz a inicialização do foundation:

```
<script>$(document).foundation();</script>
```

Se mesmo assim não der resultado, inclua o arquivo individual do JS dropdown conforme consta na documentação do mesmo na página do [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html).

```
<script src="foundation/js/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>
```

Ajuste o caminho do arquivo se for necessário.